# I have problems with json retrieved from api

Tags: c#, json, api, web

when I call this API :
https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow

I retrieve random data...
[image: response]

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => true;
HttpWebRequest request = this.GetRequest("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow");
WebResponse webResponse = request.GetResponse();
var responseText = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

anyone can help?

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO, Can you give some more information on what you have done so far? When i click the API link i get json response back

Comment: I think the answer is in here https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/compression

Comment: thank you..
The problem exactly happened when I retrieve the data by running the code above .. if i test another link it will work immediately on the same code.... but only when I use this api i can't read the json ...I got rubbish data only like the data in the image in the red area

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try the following lines of code

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
   var json = wc.DownloadString("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=creation&site=stackoverflow");
}
```

Comment: I tried this also the same results but the rubbish data changed ...but still rubbish

Answer (score 0):

Read content as follows. You should create a `StreamReader` around the stream, then call ReadToEnd.

```
using (Stream stream = webResponse.GetResponseStream())
{
   StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream, Encoding.UTF8);
   var responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I still can't read the json